# Force git to automatically delete previous versions of binary files -- is this possible?

Tags: git

I am trying to use `Github` for some academic work, as a replacement for heavy-weight cloud storage systems like Dropbox and Google Drive. This means I'd like to save PDF figures and manuscripts to my git repo, so that collaborators can clone/pull this stuff from my private repo (I have code and `.tex` files in the same repo, so for that reason, I feel that git is still appropriate). Unfortunately, the size of the `.git` folder can quickly get massive since `git` is saving these old, unwanted versions of scientific figures (we generate **a lot** before settling on something publication-worthy).

Would it be possible to have git **automatically remove** the version history of all binary (.pdf, .png, etc.) files automatically on each commit? That is, for certain filetypes, git will only keep track of the files present during the latest commit.

Alternatively, is there a simple command I can use to **periodically wipe out the binary file version history** in git, so I can run it whenever `.git` starts to get massive?

Comment: It sounds like you need [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Git is not intended as a backup service. It is built as a version control system. This means that any file that is tracked by git must have a history of changes. All changes are stored within the repository in .git.

You should **not** use Git as a replacement for Dropbox or Google Drive as these serve two entirely different purposes.

If you truly need version control for large files, then you should look at [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/). Once again, this is a **version control system**, not a file storage system. It will still store all information about all versions of the file. If you just need file storage, then you should use existing cloud storage systems instead.

Comment: That is not an answer. As stated in the question, I am trying to use git as **both a versioning system and a storage system**. It doesn't make sense to store `.tex` LaTeX manuscripts in one directory, but store the rendered PDFs in another directory -- or to store the `.py` files that generate figures in one directory, but the rendered figures in another directory. I am of course not storing **datasets** in this repo, just binary files that are logically and closely related to raw text files for which versioning is appropriate.

Comment: @LukeDavis That's your problem: **Git is not a storage system.** Versioning .txt and .py files with Git is putting it to its intended use. Storing rendered figures is abusing git for a purpose it is not supposed to solve.

Comment: @LukeDavis If you insist on using git for this purpose, you will have to live with a very large .git folder and a large download for anyone cloning your repo.

Comment: @LukeDavis: I disagree: if you have LaTeX source files, those go into Git, but the pdf from running `pdflatex` does not go in that same Git repository. The `.gitignore` for that repository probably has `*.pdf` as a line item. Similarly, a Git repo holding Python code should `.gitignore` `*.pyc` and/or `__pycache__`.

Comment: @LukeDavis The general rule of thumb is that generated files should **not** go in source control.